# i have an application created by flutter dart but it is not responsive

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, screen, responsiveness

i have an `application` created by `flutter` `dart` but it is not `responsive` i mean when i try it in my `phone` it look Very `amazing` but in `annoter` `phones` It look so `big` and not `good` at all

im wondering if there is some `thing` i have to `add` it in my `code` to make it `responsive` in all `kind` of `screens`

Comment: Hi There. Few things before this question get downvoted. Format your question properly. Add code sample to show what your widget tree looks like. Add screenshots to show what is the difference between two devices that you are noticing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a code that will be responsive to all screens
Use Mediaquery to get screen width and height and adjust the container sizes according to the screen width and height

And use Constraints to look your app screen perfect in all devices\n
Try expanded,Flexible widgets too

I think you are new to flutter and time goes on you will understand about that

Comment: LayoutBuilder (get the space left for this widget) preferable to MediaQuery (how big is the physical screen) for numerous reasons.